# TTS can't find Acapela Infovox voices (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, 32bit-64bit, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I am trying to work on speech synthesis with the danish voices from Acapela group. My OS is Windows 10. Specifically, I need to use the voices for Pyttsx, and these voices are the only decent ones around for danish.

I downloaded a trial version of the two voices (Infovox 4), but unfortunately the speech synthesis system does not *see* them. They are not available to be selected as voices for the TTS Windows system, and as a consequence I cannot see and select them via pyttsx.

I know there's already a bunch of questions on this online, and it seems to be related to 32bit voices not being compatible with 64bit systems. There doesn't seem to be any easy workaround, even though some suggest to use regedit.

Anybody has a clever solution for this? Or is just willing to give a version for dummies on how to change the regedit settings?

Pays eternal gratitude! :)